# SceneKit, экономное рисование линий

Tags: swift, macos, графика

Подскажите, каким образом можно отрисовать множество линий (около миллиона) чтобы они не выжирали память?
Сейчас делаю так:

```
var index: [Int64] = [] // сюда падают индексы 0,1,2,3,4,5... в зависимости от количества элементов массива vectorArray

let sources = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vectorArray)
let elements = SCNGeometryElement(indices: index,
                                  primitiveType: .line)

let lineGeometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [sources],
                               elements: [elements])
        
let newNode = startNode.clone()
newNode.geometry = lineGeometry
                
startNode.addChildNode(newNode)
```

Если добавлять новую ноду, то память выжирается дико.
Если же пытаться обновить ноду, удалив предыдущую, то отрисовывается только первая линия, остальные по какой то причине игнорируются.